# Saving to session seems to erase value during Repeater's OnItemDataBound Event

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is weird.  I'll try to explain my pain by the following example:

I've got an object in the Session: **Session["reportQuestionGroupingTracker"]**. It contains a List of strings.  When a string is NOT found, a new h3 header is written in the repeater via a string literal.

The problem seems to be the line: **Session["reportQuestionGroupingTracker"] = ary;**  This line seems to somehow (black)magically remove the string value in **lit.Text**.  The value is there when I breakpoint the code and seems to persist until it goes out of scope in the function(so that part works like expected) - but the string value never seems to make it to the Literal control on the ASP.NET page - they are always blank.

Note that if I comment out the problem line or this line: **if (!ary.Contains(headingText))**, the headers show (but too many of them, since every iteration triggers a header write).

```
protected void rptQuestionsGroupedByCountry_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        ArrayList ary = new ArrayList();
        if (null != Session["reportQuestionGroupingTracker"]) ary = (ArrayList)Session["reportQuestionGroupingTracker"];

        if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            string headingText = dr["Heading"].ToString();
            Literal lit = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("LiteralHeader");

            if (!ary.Contains(headingText))
            {
                lit.Text = String.Format(@"<h3 class=""questionGroupingHeader"">{0}</h3>", headingText);
                lit.Visible = true;

                ary.Add(headingText);
                Session["reportQuestionGroupingTracker"] = ary;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been on this for hours, banging my head - I've done similar things hundreds of times before, I just can't work out why it doesn't work this time!  I've tried changing the Repeater to a DataList, Tried using the Context.Items object instead of the Session, a List instead of an ArrayList, but I'm stymied.  Help!

I've also tried running it in IIS 6, just in case it was some Cassini weirdness, but the output is the same.  It's an ASP.NET 4.0 Project.

Here's the code from the aspx page:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestionsGroupedByCountry" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptQuestionsGroupedByCountry_OnItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate><table></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr><td>
    <asp:Literal ID="LiteralHeader" runat="server" Visible="false" />

    <h3 class="report-country-tag"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Numbers")%>.<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.QusetionName")%></h3>
    <div class="report-content">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Answer")%>
    <p class="date">Date Updated: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DocumentModifiedWhen")%></p>
                        </div>
    </td></tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: When are you data-binding the repeater? If you use Session, won't all the headings be in the ArrayList already the next time the page renders?

Comment: I'm clearing that session variable during Page_Load, so it's fresh each time the page starts processing.

Comment: When are you calling DataBind on the repeater? Is it possible that you're binding the repeater more than once?

Comment: Yes Michael, that's *exactly* what was happening - I wasn't noticing the second databind.  I feel very foolish.

Answer (score 2):

your problem with line

```
if (!ary.Contains(headingText))
```

You must populate literal text every time page loaded

```
    if (!ary.Contains(headingText))
    {
        ary.Add(headingText);
        Session["reportQuestionGroupingTracker"] = ary;
    }

    lit.Text = String.Format(@"<h3 class=""questionGroupingHeader"">{0}</h3>", headingText);
    lit.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Yes, but I only want the Literal.Text populated when the logic is true.  eg: in a list of 20 items there may be only 3 headings - so I want 17 of the items to have empty Literals, with only 3 of them being populated.

This logic seems to work fine!  In that when I'm in Visual Studio and breakpoint the code, the lit.Text variable DOES contain what I'm expecting - when it's supposed to be blank it is, and when it's supposed to contain a heading, it does.  The issue seems to be after this code is run during the DataBind of the RepeaterItem that the literal NEVER gets a value, unless I comment out

Answer (score 0):

As Micheal suspected, the databind routine was being hit twice for every page load.  The first time through the Session gets set properly, but the second time through, the Headers get skipped because the **if (!ary.Contains(headingText))** correctly told it to.  My bad for not noticing the two databinding hits.  I feel very foolish.  Coding while tired is no excuse for such an obvious issue.  Sorry for wasting your time!

Also I was working with too large a dataset - I'd walk through the first 5 loops and see that the value was being set and then just F5.  It wasn't until I was clearheaded this morning and just put breakpoints in every function so that I could see the execution order and understand what the heck was going on.  Then it was a headslap moment... quickly followed by a single line change to fix the issue... and then a feeling of elation.  Ain't programming fun?

Cheers and thanks for the help!

PS - Shout out to Kochobay for the line: **'...every time page loaded...'** which induced the headslapping epiphany!